# What is the functions of '@' signs in the regex below

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to understand the regex below, but I cannot understand the function of the '@' signs.

```
@(GROUP[[:space:]]+BY|HAVING|SELECT[[:space:]]+DISTINCT)[[:space:]]+@i
```

Comment: It's the regex delimiters indicating the start and end of the regex

Comment: The `@`'s are acting as the delimitation for the regex.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have it or can I omit it?

Comment: You have to have SOME deliminator for the regex. It can really be any character/symbol that you are 100% sure you won't have in your match string. Such as `%, #, &, or /`.

Comment: @PenguinCoder They can be in your match string as long as you escape them properly.

Answer (score 4):

To put it as an answer they are the regex delimiters.

They are necessary, other common delimiters are / or #